# bash populating number of variables

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop, wc, auto-populating

I have a text file. Using `wc -l` I can determine their are 15 lines. I am trying to create a number of variables based on the output of `wc -l`. So if I get 15 lines, I want 15 variables named `var1 var2`  and so on. Does anyone know a way to do this? The code I made seems to think i am doing a command, instead of varaible declaration. This is the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
VARIABLEAMT=$( wc -l myfile.txt )
NUMBER=0
while [ $NUMBER -le $VARIABLEAMT ];
do
        var${NUMBER}=0
        let NUMBER++
done




exit 0
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want an array instead?

Comment: Arrays are generally preferable to putting numbers in variable names. If that'll work, use `readarray -t var <myfile.txt`, and then get the array contents with `"${var[0]}"` etc.

Comment: My xy problem guess is that you want `mapfile -t somearray < myfile.txt`

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know it would be that simple. Thank you, I will put them all in a array instead.

Comment: The myfile contains a integer and then the date next to it. Is their a way to parse just the integers with readarray, or should I use awk, ex awk ' {print $1}'?

Comment: consider updating the question with some sample data from `myfile.txt`; and add a description of how you want that data stored in the array